# MongoDB, Mongoose Find if Array Contains/Includes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Basically let's say that I need to find an element by multiple unique names that are stored in an string array type. [String]

```
const ExampleSchema = new Schema({
  names: [String],
  etc...
});
```

I have a string that is included in this array of a document and I wanna find the document using this unique string. Is this even possible?

Something like $contains *($contains does not exist in mongoose, I just copied how $in works)*

```
ExampleModel.find({{ "names": { "$contains": my_unique_string } });
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$in` work? if you want partial match mongoDB accepts `regex`

Comment: I wanna check if my unique string is in the array of the document. I don't want to check if a string in my document is in an array. If that makes sense.

Basically I want to find one document that has a names array that includes my string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html) with [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html), it can allow to check string is in `names` array or not,

```
ExampleModel.find({
  $expr: {
    $in: [my_unique_string, "$names"]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X_0zvNhF3zM)

Comment: Which do you think is better the regex method or this?

Comment: Its depends on your requirement, $regex will search inside the string, and $in will check exact equal string, you can check the difference between [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GplPCzSqfS2) and in answer link.